# DNS binds points to an address not in it configurations

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns

After setting up bind/dns on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS I get the following, let me say that this address is not part of my network at all. It's not part of any settings.

```
ping www.dynasty.local
PING www.dynasty.local (198.105.244.228) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Address should be `192.168.0.200`.

When I do `nslookup`:

```
juancc2007md@ns1:~$ nslookup dynasty.local
Server:     209.18.47.61
Address:    209.18.47.61#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   dynasty.local
Address: 198.105.244.228 # should be 192.168.0.200
Name:   dynasty.local
Address: 198.105.254.228 # should be 192.168.0.200
```

`nslookup` up on the `ns1` server:

```
juancc2007md@ns1:~$ nslookup ns1.dynasty.local
Server:     209.18.47.61 # these are my isp dns
Address:    209.18.47.61 # 53 these are my isp dns
** server can't find ns1.dynasty.local: NXDOMAIN
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit on your setup. Why do you expect dynasty.local to be 192.168.0.200? Why do you even expect to find .local TLD in DNS? It's commonly used for ZeroConf, and should probably not be in DNS. And why do you expect ns1.dynasty.local to excist? If you set up the DNS server, correct the record on the DNS server?

Comment: hi thanks, the dns was setup on the 192.168.0.200 address. .local is a dns setup for internal use only.

Comment: You should probably not use .local, as it is reserved for mDNS. In addition, you have to check the records of the DNS server. What is actually defined in the zone file?

Answer (score 0):

This [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/352466/385348) answer says to search files on your computer that contain the bad address. Although that answer suggests manually checking various files for the string, you can automate the approach with this command:

```
sudo grep -rnwI --exclude-dir={boot,dev,media,mnt,proc,root,run,sys,/tmp,tmpfs,var} -E "198.105.244.228" /
```